# C++ , create structure with an optional value

Tags: c++, struct

I need to create structure with an optional value :

```
typedef struct pkt_header{
    unsigned short Packet_Type;
    unsigned short Unprotected_Payload_Length;
    unsigned short Protected_Payload_Length; // optional (present/not present)
    unsigned short Version;   
} PKT_HEADER;
```

How can i sometimes use `pkt_header->Protected_Payload_Length` and sometimes not use this value in a `struct` when the field is not present ?
My first idea is to declare `unsigned char * Protected_Payload_Length` and pass `NULL` when i not use the field and use the `unsigned char*` for store my `unsigned short` value.

```
typedef struct pkt_header{
    unsigned short Packet_Type;
    unsigned short Unprotected_Payload_Length;
    unsigned char * Protected_Payload_Length; // optional
    unsigned short Version;   
} PKT_HEADER;
```

I prepare my packet like this (and send this):

```
PKT_HEADER header;
header.Packet_Type                = 0x0001;
header.Unprotected_Payload_Length = 0x0b00;
header.Protected_Payload_Length   = NULL; 
header.Version                    = 0x0000;
```

I receive response and do this :

```
PKT_HEADER * header= (PKT_HEADER*)recvbuf;
printf("Packet_Type                : %04x\n", header->Packet_Type);
printf("Unprotected_Payload_Length : %04x\n", header->Unprotected_Payload_Length);
printf("Version                    : %04x\n", header->Version);
```

But in this case, if i understand correctly, `unsigned char * Protected_Payload_Length` contain a pointer with a length of 4 bytes then `header->Protected_Payload_Length` contain `4 bytes` but i need `0 byte` because the value/field is not present in this precise case.

Do I have to declare an appropriate structure in the data format or is there some other way to play with the structures?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is inheritance an option?

Comment: you have to take into account padding and byte order. Reinterpreting a char array as `PKT_HEADER` is the wrong way. You need to use `memcpy`

Comment: @idclev463035818,  Thank you. Sorry i don't understand correctly your first question.  Your second comment is when i prepare my packet or when i cast the received buffer ?  (sorry i'm rather new to c ++)

Comment: Is this `C++` or `C`? Tag says `C++` code looks like typicial  `C` code. If this is `C++` then which version? `C++17` has `std::optional`.

Comment: @MarekR `std::optional<T>` takes at least as much space as `T`, so it wont help

Comment: @idclev463035818 question is so messy it is hard to tell if this is a problem. For me it smells like XY problem. Proper solution depends on functional requirements which are not described.

Comment: @MarekR "...contain 4 bytes but i need 0 byte because the value/field is not present in this precise case." though yes, it is obvious that the root problem is elsewhere and this question focuses on a Y

Comment: Sorry if my question is incorrectly asked.

Comment: note that this looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Reading between the lines it is apparent that you have 1-2 misunderstandings. Having to define two types seems to be the smaller problem. Please don't modify this question to ask for something else, but maybe you want to ask another one where you describe your actual problem that you want to solve.

Comment: @MarekR, Thank you also for your comments.

Comment: this is C code, please change the title and the tag

Comment: @Sopel if OP says it is C++ and compiles it as C++, then it is C++

Comment: @idclev463035818, yes indeed and I am currently trying to understand why I am told that it is C and not C++.

Comment: @Ephemeral one reason is that  `typedef struct pkt_header { ... } PKT_HEADER;` is C. You can write it also in C++, but there is no good reason to do so

Comment: @idclev463035818, Thank you very much for your time and explanations. But on [this website](https://cpp.developpez.com/cours/cpp/?page=page_5) (French cpp education) i can see this same declaration `section 3.1.6 
Type aliases`. I'm confuse.

Comment: @Ephemeral I don't know french, so I cannot say much, but trying to teach C and C++ at the same time sounds like a very bad idea to me

Comment: @idclev463035818, No problem i understand. Thank you for all.

Comment: for example you cannot explain unions in C and C++ without explaining that they are quite different in C and C++, and (given my lack of french) I dont see that they mention that

Comment: @idclev463035818, You are right, this website does not specify any differences. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware. Structs can have padding, members are not necessarily adjacent in memory. Moreover reinterpreting something as a `PKT_HEADER` when that something is not a `PKT_HEADER` object is not allowed. Instead of casting:

```
PKT_HEADER * header= (PKT_HEADER*)recvbuf;
```

you probably should use `memcpy`. Having said this, now to your actual question...

If you rely on members having a specific order in the struct, then inheritance is not an option. In memory the base object comes first, then the derived members, you cannot mix that. For example

```
 struct foo {
     int x;
 };
 struct bar : foo {
     int y;
     int z;
 };
```

Then a `bar` object will have in memory

```
 | x | optional padding | y | optional padding | z | optional padding |
```

There is no simple way to get `| y | x | z |`.

If you want two different types the easiest is to define two different types:

```
struct PKT_HEADER_A {
    unsigned short Packet_Type;
    unsigned short Unprotected_Payload_Length;
    unsigned short Protected_Payload_Length; // present
    unsigned short Version;   
};


struct PKT_HEADER_B {
    unsigned short Packet_Type;
    unsigned short Unprotected_Payload_Length;
    //unsigned short Protected_Payload_Length; // not present
    unsigned short Version;   
};
```

Note that your way to `typedef` the struct is a C-ism. It is not necessary (and not recommended) in C++.

Comment: Thank you very much i will read your answer carefully.

Comment: an if around the memcopy would handle this with 1 struct right? You'd have to copy out the bytes you want.. id do helper function `header *CopyHeaderFromStructWithOptional(struct)` fields? would that be bad? I'd not want to duplicate the structs

Comment: For your first point , I use `PKT_HEADER * header= (PKT_HEADER*)recvbuf;` because I was inspired by this code [Winsock Sniffer code in C](https://gist.github.com/Accalmie/d328287c05f0a417892f).

Comment: @Daij-Djan sorry don't understand your comment. In `PKT_HEADER * header= (PKT_HEADER*)recvbuf;` you are copying aynhow. It is the cast that is not allowed (when `recvbuf` does not point to an actual `PKT_HEADER` object). `memcpy` does the same

Comment: @Ephemeral C++ is not C. Translating C idioms to C++ directly is a sure path to a world of pain

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at the packing done on NanoPb or Protobuff , because it sounds like you have a packing problem. Data should be pieced together before sending, and the Packet_Type would encode which header to decode/encode with.

If you can't properly pack/unpack, an alternative is to create both

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short Packet_Type;
    unsigned short Unprotected_Payload_Length;
    unsigned short Protected_Payload_Length;
    unsigned short Version;   
} PKT_HEADER_FULL;

typedef struct {
    unsigned short Packet_Type;
    unsigned short Unprotected_Payload_Length;
    unsigned short Version;   
} PKT_HEADER_SHORT;
```

then create your a packet header

```
typedef union u{
    PKT_HEADER_FULL full;
    PKT_HEADER_SHORT concat;
}PKT_HEADER;


// or as this

typedef struct{
    unsigned short Protected_Payload_Length;
    unsigned short version
}longform;

typedef struct{
    unsigned short Packet_Type;
    unsigned short Unprotected_Payload_Length;
    union u{
        longform l;
        unsigned short version;
    };
} PKT_HEADER;
```

Then the data coming in could be decoded either way (again, depending on Packet_type), and the remaining space can be ignored. A caveat to this method is you can't use `sizeof(PKT_HEADER)` because the struct size will always be the larger value.